# Is there a noun for an estranged adult child?

Tags: nouns, synonyms, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that means "estranged adult child".

I want to be able to say "I'm a [estranged adult child]"

Is there a word for "estranged adult child"?

Comment: If you refer to a child over the age of majority having lost former closeness and affection with his parents, I don't think that you will find a single word for such definition.

Comment: Not an answer but… [My parents have disowned me](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=578359623&sxsrf=AM9HkKkdTZEcMQ26gBykqTMRsLuCb9etrw:1698804379930&q=%22parents+have+disowned+me%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR6-6826GCAxUXVPEDHSHgA6QQ0pQJegQIVhAB&biw=1130&bih=619&dpr=2.5) = *refuse to acknowledge or maintain any connection with.*

Comment: Not exactly the right thing, but you might want to consider "black sheep".

Comment: You might say "I'm completely independent" or "I'm on my own". Sorry for your pain!

Comment: I would suggest *estranger*.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific situation, such as within a particular ethnic group? Do you mean legal disinheriting, parents refusing to support children (which with university etc can include adult children), or something else (e.g. not talking to, whether done with a formal declaration or not, lost contact)? I suspect there may be a term in communities like the Amish where shunning of relatives is common, and might be a multi-word term when it comes to filling out university applications.

Comment: Absent context, it wouldn't be obvious to me whether an "estranged adult child" is someone who disowned their parents, or whose parents disowned *them*. Or perhaps the motivation for the estrangement came equally from both parties.

Comment: Now that you've pointed that out, I want a word for each of those situations :-)

Comment: Why is this closed? It says it needs details but what else is there to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Forums that deal with such matters generally have no other term except the abbreviations EC, ED, and ES -- that is, estranged child, estranged daughter, estranged son.

However, even those are limited to the specialized arena.  As one estranged parent put it in an [essay](https://medium.com/any-writers/blindsided-a-raw-account-of-a-sons-estrangement-3aa8dc2a6e87):

> To belong to these estrangement groups requires adopting a different language, a language of acronyms that took me a minute to decipher. I hope you never have to use them: ES Estranged Son, ED Estranged Daughter, EC Estranged Child or Children, EG Estranged Grandchildren (their parent’s choice, not the grandparents’), DIL Toxic Daughter-in-Law, SIL Toxic Son-in-Law, IL Toxic In-laws and so on.